# Ajax Request with Rails 5 App getting error 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails 5 app where I'm simply trying to implement a like button feature. In my case, I'm doing upvotes. When the signed in user clicks the button it should increment by 1. I'm using devise for users and admins.

My show.html.erb

```
<% if member_signed_in? %>
 <div class"movie-votes">
   <medium id="votes"><%= @movie.votes %> members like this film</medium>
   <button id="upvote" type="submit">I Like this Film</button>
 </div>
```

My Ajax request

```
"use strict";
console.log("loaded");
$(document).ready(function(){

 var member = $("member");
 var password = $("password");
$("#upvote").click(function() {
 console.log("clicked");
 var id = $(this).data("id");

$.ajax({
beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(member + ":" + password)); },
   url: "/movies/votes",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    member: "test@example.com",
    password: "password",
    id: id,
 votes: true
  },
  success: function() {
    var vote_counter = $("#votes");
    // console.log(vote_counter);
    var current_vote = parseInt($("#votes").html());
    vote_counter.html(current_vote + 1);
    alert(vote_counter);
  }
  })
 })
})
```

**MoviesController**

```
before_action :set_movies, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update, :votes]

def votes
 @movie.update(votes: @movie.votes + 1)
end

private 

def set_movies
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

The error I'm getting when I open up the console on localhost.

```
loaded
clicked
jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:10246 POST http://localhost:3000/movies/votes 401 (Unauthorized)
```

This happens after I click the "I like this film" button. Sidenote, I disabled turbolinks for now because that has been the issue in the past.
If needed, here's my [GitHub](https://github.com/kylestengline/moviesmoviesmovies/tree/development)

Comment: did you research for similar questions?

Comment: posting the entire code for `votes` action would be of much more help than just few lines. This is a very unsecure way of adding a voting feature. you should also check , whether this user has already voted or not.

Comment: What response is the votes action rendering?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: You've forgotten to include the necessary details about the failure of the program. To be able to help you quickly and sufficiently, we'll need to know what is happening with your program. Compare your desired result with what is actually happening. Be sure to include any error messages, or lack of error messages that you think you should get. Try to debug this and find the last place in the code that you know everything was going right up until.

Comment: totally agree with what @MatthewCliatt said. there is too few information on the question about the error and from where it is getting generated.

Comment: My apologies. I shouldn't have asked this question while half asleep. Please find the updated version above. 

Thank you, @MatthewCliatt for the guide and constructive criticism. Moving forward, I'll be more detailed with my errors.

Comment: +1 Because I would like to see the answer to this question, and because with the effort added to format and provide necessary information, now it looks like a great question.

Comment: You say that this isn't working with Ajax. Does that mean it works without the Ajax call and just refreshing the page?

Comment: Thank you, @MatthewCliatt, I appreciate that.
So, the page won't display the new number at all. AJAX or otherwise.

Comment: Does the transaction get rolled back? You can look at the output from the terminal the server is running in and see where the SQL statement is generated and applied. You should see a line that says either "commit transaction" or "rollback transaction".

Comment: In the terminal I get this error...

`Started POST "/movies/votes" for ::1 at 2016-05-01 13:56:56 -0400
Processing by MoviesController#votes as */*
  Parameters: {"member"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "votes"=>"true"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`
No SQL statements, which is odd.

Comment: Please stop using bold letters everywhere. it is less readable.

Answer (score -2):

Clearly the issue is due to the Authentication. apart from Authentication, you still have couple of issues in your code such as

- you are not passing the `id` of the `movie` to `votes` action.
- Your controller assumes that the `params[:id]` is there and hence tries to find the movie but it couldn't get it.

In your `html` code, add a data-attribute in `button` tag:

```
<% if member_signed_in? %>
 <div class"movie-votes">
   <medium id="votes"><%= @movie.votes %> members like this film</medium>
   <button data-movie="<%= @movie.id %>" id="upvote">I Like this Film</button>
 </div>
```

In your `Ajax` code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

     var member = $("member");
     var password = $("password"); // <-- this is the actual password you are passing here?
    $("#upvote").click(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr("data-movie");

    $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(member + ":" + password)); },
       url: "/movies/votes",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        member: "test@example.com",
        password: "password",
        id: id,
        votes: true
      },
      success: function() {
        var vote_counter = $("#votes");
        // console.log(vote_counter);
        var current_vote = parseInt($("#votes").html());
        vote_counter.html(current_vote + 1);
        alert(vote_counter);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PS: I am not sure if its a right way of building a voting feature. I would suggest using a gem like `act_as_votable` which will be much more neat.